# Attempts at distributed deciphering of Linear A

Tags: undeciphered-writing, philology

Possibly related: [Current prospective efforts in the decipherment of ancient scripts](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17004/current-prospective-efforts-in-the-decipherment-of-ancient-scripts)

Are there any active attempts at coding and indexing all available examples of Linear A in a manner that would support review and attempts at deciphering using a distributed architecture similar to that in use at Berkeley for [SETI@home](http://setiathome.ssl.berkeley.edu/) and at Stanford for [Folding@home](http://folding.stanford.edu/)?

If not, are there insurmountable challenges that would prevent this type of brute-force deciphering?

Comment: I am not sure brute force deciphering would help. First of all you need to understand the nature of the language (is it analytical?, is it agglutinative?, is it an isolate or does it belong to a language family?). If there is more than just one language, then it could be even more complicated. To give another example, eteo-cypriot has not been deciphered although we have "Rosetta stones", that is to say billingual inscriptions.